# Storing sparse data using ORC

Tags: hbase, orc

I'm trying to port some data from Hbase to ORC to improve on write performance. In Hbase, my data is stored in a total of 10 columns against a rowkey. Now as we're using Hbase, we needn't worry about the sparsity of these columns. Even in case most rows have only two columns with non zero values, it would be okay as Hbase would only store 2 columns.

My first instinct while porting data was to convert the above column-qualifier to values relation to a map. However, this is not very efficient for retrieval. I'm trying to understand how ORC interprets nulls - would it be better if I store the values as 10 separate columns rather than as a map? This matrix would be very sparse in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Write performance of ORC is probably worse than Hbase, ORC is used for read heavy use cases and it is optimized to store large amount of sorted data. This is when it shines. Most if its features are organized around speeding up read queries, like predicate push down for example. I think without knowing much about your data, Hbase is probably a better solution for write heavy operations. Answering your question: it is almost mandatory to split up your data to separate columns since ORC is a columnar oriented format. It does handle sparse data very well.

Comment: could you elaborate on why you say it handles sparse data very well? I'm currently investigating ORC for a read-heavy use case. The objects I'm writing to ORC each contain a list of enum values. My current plan is to encode each enum value in this list as a separate column in ORC, but am a little worried since I can't find any information on how it handles sparse data. Any information you can provide is very valuable. Thanks!

Comment: Answered my question below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [ORC documentation](https://orc.apache.org/docs/stripes.html):

> In ORC files, each column is stored in several streams that are stored next to each other in the file. For example, an integer column is **represented as two streams: PRESENT, which uses one with a bit per value recording if the value is non-null, and DATA, which records the non-null values.** If all of a column’s values in a stripe are non-null, the PRESENT stream is omitted from the stripe.

This means that, in the worst case, each null value costs you **exactly one bit**. In the average case, ORC compresses these streams further if you specify a compression algorithm. So you could end up with a situation where a null value costs you way less than one bit.

This being said, it's hard to say if that's more efficient for your particular application. If you need to read specific values (i.e: columns) out of each row then your read performance might improve a lot. I/O can be further improved if your read is conditional e.g: if COL2 == "someValue" since ORC has indices that support skipping column chunks.